# sum non NA elements only, but if all NA then return NA

Tags: r, data.table

I think I already got really good answers on the comments, but I will rephrase the question for future reference.

I am trying to sum by groups using data.table. The problem is that some groups **only** have NA. For these groups I would like the sum to return NA. However, if there is one group that has one value different that NA, I would like to get the sum of the non-NA values.

```
A <- data.table(col1= c('A','A','B','B','C','C'),  
                col2= c(NA,NA,2,3,NA,4))
```

This without adding the argument `na.rm = T`, group C returns NA when it should return 4.

```
A[, sum(col2), by = .(col1)]
   col1 V1
1:    A NA
2:    B  5
3:    C NA
```

However, adding `na.rm = T` returns 0 in group A when it should return NA.

```
A[, sum(col2, na.rm = T), by = .(col1)]
   col1 V1
1:    A  0
2:    B  5
3:    C  4
```

The approach that i like the best is the one that sandipan suggested in the comments, which is akin to the function I wrote below:

```
ifelse(all(is.na(col2)), NA, sum(col2, na.rm = T)
```

I created a function to get around it, but I am not sure whether there is an already built-in way to get around this:

```
sum.na <- function(df){

  if (all(is.na(df))){

    suma <- NA
  }  
  else {    
    suma <- sum(df, na.rm = T)
  }

  return(suma)
}
```

Comment: Could you show an example including a data.table? Generally... `DT[!is.na(x), sumx := sum(x), by=id]` should work, I think.

Comment: if `x` is a vector this should work: `ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, sum(x, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: @sandipan Fyi, there's `anyNA(x)` equivalent to `any(is.na(x))` .. hm, just realized that probably doesn't help here.

Comment: @Frank thanks for the information.

Comment: Thank you all. I posted a reproducible example above. The answer i like the post is the one from sandipan.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question even though you already had answers.  It makes the post much more valuable to future users.

Comment: Yeah, I also prefer @sandipan 's approach. I just found a variant of it it my own code: `function(x)
    if   (all(is.na(x))) x[NA_integer_]
    else sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)` This ensures that the result has the same class as `x` when it's all NA and also skips the unnecessary `ifelse`. Btw, dieal, you'll need to use @ before someone's name if you want to "ping" or alert them to your message (as I did by @ sandipan here).

Comment: I mostly agree with Barker, but rather than putting the answer into the question it would be best to put it in an actual answer. Since the commenters seems to not want to take the time to write a detailed answer, you can feel free to do so. Answering your own question is encouraged when applicable!

Comment: @Gregor thank you for the suggestions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the suggestions from other users, I will post the answer to my question. The solution was provided by @sandipan in the comments above:

As noted in the question, if you need to sum the values of one column which contains NAs,there are two good approaches:

1) using ifelse:

```
A[, (ifelse(all(is.na(col2)), col2[NA_integer_], sum(col2, na.rm = T))), 
  by = .(col1)]
```

2) define a function as suggested by @Frank:

```
suma = function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) x[NA_integer_] else sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)

A[, suma(col2), by = .(col1)]
```

Note that I added NA_integer_ as @Frank pointed out because I kept getting errors about the types.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sum_` from `hablar`

```
library(hablar)
A[, as.numeric(sum_(col2)), .(col1)]
#   col1 V1
#1:    A NA
#2:    B  5
#3:    C  4
```