# na.rm in custom function returns zero's

Tags: r, function, na

I have a data frame that I wrote a function for that includes a na.rm=T argument. Here is the data frame:

```
df<- structure(list(BLG = c(38.4615384615385, 33.3333333333333, 0), 
    LMB = c(20, 100, NA), RSF = c(100, 100, NA), WHC = c(66.6666666666667, 
    33.3333333333333, NA), BLC = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), GSF = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WSH = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), CCF = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), group = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

This is the function:

```
estimate = function(df, y_true, na.rm=T) {
  sqrt(colSums((t(t(df) - y_true))^2, na.rm=T) / 3) / y_true * 100
}

y_true<- c(28, 50, 77, 46, 80, 12, 100, 50)
```

Run function:

```
final <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  group_modify( ~ as.data.frame.list(estimate(., y_true)))
```

The issue is that when all three observations are NA, the function returns 0 instead of NA (columns 6:9 of `final`). If only a fraction of the observations are NA, the function works as intended (column 5 of `final`).

I'm guessing this is due to how I formatted the na.rm argument in the function, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: That's the default behavior of `colSums` (and `sum`). From `?colSums`: "If there are no values in a range to be summed over (after removing missing values with na.rm = TRUE), that component of the output is set to 0 (*Sums) or NaN (*Means), consistent with sum and mean."

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470277/sum-non-na-elements-only-but-if-all-na-then-return-na

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize the issue was with 'colSums' so my original search didn't yield anything helpful